# Binding Column properties of Xceed DataGrid to viewmodel property attribute

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, xceed-datagrid

I'm binding to an Xceed DataGridControl (Community Edition) with `AutoCreatedColumns`

```cs
ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items
```

I would like to mark the created columns' `ReadOnly` property based on the `Editable` attribute on the viewmodel property.

```cs
 class ItemViewModel : ViewModelBase {

     [Editable(false)] 
     public string Id { get; set; }

     string _comment;
     [Editable(true)]
     public string Comment {
         get { return _comment; }
         set {
              _comment = value;
              NotifyOfPropertyChanged(() => Comment);
         }
     // Other properties ...

 }
```

Is this possible? or is there another way I could hook into the creation of the column to inspect the property that is being bound and programmatically set ReadOnly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the optimal solution is to just hook up to `ItemsSourceChangeCompleted` event like this:

```cs
void _dataGrid_ItemsSourceChangeCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridControl control = (DataGridControl)sender;
    Type itemType = control.ItemsSource.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    foreach (var col in control.Columns)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = itemType.GetProperty(col.FieldName);
        if (propInfo != null)
        {
            EditableAttribute editableAttribute = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<EditableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            col.ReadOnly = (editableAttribute == null || !editableAttribute.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            col.ReadOnly = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could bind the cell `ReadOnly` property to your editable attribute as described [here](http://xceed.com/CS/forums/thread/27955.aspx).

If you know what columns you want to display you could simplify the solution above and bind the column `ReadOnly` property like this:

```cs
public class EditableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = value.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0].GetProperty(parameter.ToString());
            if (propInfo != null)
            {
                EditableAttribute editableAttribute = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<EditableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
                return (editableAttribute == null || !editableAttribute.Value);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
    <xcdg:Column FieldName="Id" 
                 ReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=DataGridControl.ItemsSource, 
                    Converter={StaticResource EditableConverter}, ConverterParameter=Id}" />
    <xcdg:Column FieldName="Comment" 
                 ReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                    Path=DataGridControl.ItemsSource, 
                    Converter={StaticResource EditableConverter}, ConverterParameter=Comment}" />
</xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
```

But then, you might as well turn off `AutoCreateColumns` and define the `Columns` collection by yourself in code (or turn off `AutoCreateItemProperties` and create your own `DataGridCollectionViewSource` where you set each `DataGridItemProperty.IsReadOnly` appropriately).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up hard coding the columns in the XAML in this case, but this is good info for the future!